# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS に VirtualBox をインストールしたい

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

Ubuntu 20.04 LTS に VirtualBox をインストールする方法を教えてください｡

Comment: こんな記事が参考になるのでは？ [VirtualBox のインストールと設定（Ubuntu 上）](https://www.kkaneko.jp/tools/ubuntu/virtualboxubuntu.html)

Answer (score 1):

手っ取り早くは以下のコマンドを実行するだけです。

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install virtualbox -y
```

**参考:**
[UbuntuにVirtualBoxをインストールする方法](https://news.mynavi.jp/techplus/article/20190227-777688/)

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntuパッケージを調べる方法

- ターミナル (CLI) 使用するには, 例えば次のように

  - ```bash
    $ apt list virtual*
    ```
- GUIでは, Ubuntu Software など起動し 「探す」で "VirtualBox" などタイプする
- Webブラウザー使うなら [Ubuntu パッケージ検索](https://packages.ubuntu.com/) から

  - キーワード: virtualbox
  - 検索対象:￼ パッケージ名のみ
  - Distribution: focal (20.04LTS)
- Ubuntu正式ではないパッケージ

  - [Ubuntu PPA (Personal Package Archives)](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas) で調べる
  - 提供元 [Download VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) から [Download VirtualBox for Linux Hosts](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads)

※ Ubuntuの正式ではないパッケージは, 正式なパッケージよりも新しいバージョンが利用できる可能性があります
(回答してる時点での)最新は VirtualBox 7.0.4 で, 正式の 6.1.38 より新しいようです (新しいほうがよいかどうかは不明)

---

パッケージをインストールするなら, 上記それぞれの方法で
ターミナル使用するなら以下のように (上記で調べたパッケージ名を指定)

```bash
$ sudo apt install virtualbox
```